# Brake cable shaking at the end of the brake caliper

Tags: brakes, cable

I recently noticed on my bike that the brake cable housing is shaking at the point where it joins the brake caliper. This is pretty irritating since the cable housing moves whenever I use the brake.

Here are some pictures

[image]

[image]

[image]

Notice that the metal ring on the cable has moved between the three pictures.

I usually hire a professional to fix these problems but have decided to do it on my own from now. I could not find anything from some google searches to solve this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The fittings you see are used for adjusting brake cable tension.  After the "rough" length of the cable has been set by sliding the cable in and out of the clamp at the other end, the left-most knob is "unscrewed" to do fine adjustment.  Then the thin nut (a "lock nut") is tightened back against the brake lever housing to hold the adjustment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the initial cable adjustment is too loose. You need to adjust (remove the slack)from the cable at the cable pinch bolt on the brake caliper or arm.  Before you make these adjustments verify that the brake pads are not worn to the point of needing replacement as you will need to do this again when the pads are replaced.

Answer (score 1):

That ring is supposed to be a lock ring.  Tighten it up against the brake.

Comment: All my attempts to push it in were futile. I don't see any mechanism to tighten it. 

I just took another pic. This is what happens when I press and release the brake. http://goo.gl/DBH2Ye. The part which is loose is not the nut on the brake lever but the metal cover on the brake cable.

Comment: You need to pull the slack out of the cable.  With the much slack loosen at the brake and pull cable.